# Docker crashed - Unable to create an instance of Docker.App: Unable to create an instance of Docker.ApiServices.Update.UpdateCheckTimer:

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

After installing docker in my Windows 10 PRO, it is throwing below error.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s02cc.png)

Steps tried:

1. Tried "Reset to factory Default" - Dint worked
2. Also ensured wsl is enabled in the machine.
3. Tried restarting and reinstalling the docker - Dint worked.

Is there any particular step to be followed to install docker in Windows 10 pro. It works perfectly fine in Windows 10 Home edition.

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

- Install docker with FULL access of Admin privileges on your user profile
- Install latest WSL packages
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package
- perform step 5 and 6
- restart the system
- if wsl --list --verbose is working then your docker setup is installed and working properly.
- now try to reopen the docker with Admin user.
- It should work and try basic docker commands
  -> docker container ls
  -> docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

It worked for me, hope it will work for you too..